# Probability of more than one, but no more than three?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the following problem... Hope someone can enlighten me.

On the motherboard of a device there are 20 different processors of which 5 of them are faulty. We know that there is 1 or more faults on the motherboard. In an attempt to find the error, we select 4 random processors for testing.

What is the probability that more than 1 of the processors is faulty, but no more than 3?

**Solution tldr:** Given the suggestion per BruceET, using the hypergeometric probability distribution, I figured the probability as follows.

$\frac{\binom 5 2 \binom {15}2}{\binom {20}4} + \frac{\binom 53 \binom {15}1}{\binom {20}4} = 0.2477\ \ \ $which checks with the problem's reference values.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: @5xum I see. Mainly I was looking for suggestions and interpretations to the question and generally how to proceed, not necessarily solutions. Should I avoid this type of question in the future?

Comment: What's an "error"? Does it refer to a faulty processor? I'm confused because you explicitly wrote that "there are 1 or more errors on the motherboard". But that's redundant since it's mentioned that 5 processors are faulty.

Comment: Error and faulty should be the same. Edited the question now

Comment: The question is asking for the probability that exactly two or exactly three of the four randomly selected processors are faulty given that five of the twenty processors are faulty.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig But which one, or is it the sum of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sampling of processors is without replacement, so this would be
a hypergeometric distribution instead of a binomial. Thus one of the two
terms is as follows:

$$P(X = 2) = \frac{{5 \choose 2}{15 \choose 2}}{{20 \choose 4}}.$$

In R statistical software, the answer (total of two terms as in the
comment of @N.F.Taussig) is computed as:

```
sum(dhyper(2:3,  5, 15,  4))
## 0.247678
```